# LINQ: Select a collection?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to use LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<String> debtors = (from expense in CurrentExpenses
                               where expense.WhoPaid == username
                               select expense.WhoOwes.AsEnumerable()).Distinct();
```

(`username` and `WhoPaid` are strings, `WhoOwes` is `ICollection<String>`)

What I want to do is get an `IEnumerable` of, for each `expense` where `username` paid, all the people who owe for it. I'm not really sure how to do it. Here is the compiler error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code you've provided doesn't compile because you're trying to assign *a sequence of* a sequence of strings (each top-level sequence coming from a *specific* expense) to a reference that expects a sequence of strings.

Going by the return-type of your query, I assume you only need a sequence containing all the debtors for the user? If so, you need to *flatten* the result sequence.

```
// implicitly IEnumerable<string>
var debtors = CurrentExpenses.Where(expense => expense.WhoPaid == username)
                             .Select(expense => expense.WhoOwes)
                             .SelectMany(debtors => debtors) // flatten sequence
                             .Distinct();
```

(you can use a single `SelectMany` clause to do the projection and flattening together.)

or, in query syntax:

```
var debtors = (from expense in CurrentExpenses
               where expense.WhoPaid == username
               from debtor in expense.WhoOwes
               select debtor).Distinct();
```

If you need to find all expenses paid by the user and their associated debtors, you can stop at the first filter:

```
// implicitly IEnumerable<Expense>
var expensesPaidByUser = CurrentExpenses.Where(expense => expense.WhoPaid == username);
```

The debtors associated with each expense are *already* encapsulated in the`Expense` object, so you *probably* don't need a query more complicated than this; it's already *effectively* a sequence of a sequence of debtors grouped by expense.

If you do want a separate type to hold an expense and its associated debtors, you can do this with an anonymous type, although I don't see why its necessary in your case:

```
// implictly IEnumerable<anonymousType>
var debtorsByExpense = CurrentExpenses.Where(expense => expense.WhoPaid == username)
                                      .Select(expense => new { Expense = expense, Debtors = expense.WhoOwes });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
var debtors = ...
```

instead of

```
IEnumerable<String> debtors = ...
```

The return type of LINQ expressions is often difficult to determine for the programmer. The `var` keyword tells the compiler to infer the type automatically, so you don't need to. Hover your mouse cursor over `var` in your IDE to see what the compiler has inferred.

Comment: +1.  Compiler is using two features in this case for LINQ.  They are named 'Implicit Variable Types' (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) and 'Anonymous Types' (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)